# Where can I find the black speech dialog used in 'Desolation of Smaug'?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, languages, desolation-of-smaug

I want to read the actual [Black Speech](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Speech) sentences uttered by the Orcs and by Sauron in [*The Desolation of Smaug*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit:_The_Desolation_of_Smaug). Does anybody know what they were or where can I find them?

[image: Sauron speaks to Gandalf]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say they don't exist. Probably just voice-sounding gibberish for the film. As I recall, The Black Speech was not a "completed" language like Elvish almost was.

Comment: You can find a subbed transcript here; http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitleserve/sub/5467945 failing that, are they not in the actual book; http://readanybooks.net/fantasticfiction/The_Hobbit/?

Comment: @Richard There is no Black Speech in _The Hobbit_ (book), and Sauron/The Necromancer does not have a speaking part in any language ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Black Speech for the *Hobbit* movies (as well as for the *Lord of the Rings* movies) was worked out by David Salo, a professional linguist employed for that job.  You can read his thoughts and rationale for it at [his own website](https://web.archive.org/web/20190209234019/http://midgardsmal.com/category/blackspeech/).

According to Salo, Orcs in the movies actually mostly speak in Orkish, not Black Speech, and [he lists every invented Orkish word that has been used in the movies so far](https://web.archive.org/web/20170830212621/http://midgardsmal.com/2014/01/).

> Although there is quite a bit of Orkish in the films of The Hobbit, the vocabulary involved in the dialogue is quite small ... Because of the limited nature of this vocabulary, it is possible to list all of the Orkish words that have appeared in the Hobbit films thus far.

I'm not aware if any of the actual dialogue itself has been published yet, but potential future sources would include DVD subtitles, scripts and tie-in books.

Comment: Wouldn't the Orc leaders at least use black speech when addressing their lord Sauron? Seems kind of disrespectful.

Comment: See LotR Appendix F: "he had desired to make it the language of all those that served him, but he failed in that purpose" and "they had no language of their own, but took what they could of other tongues and perverted it to their own liking, yet they made only brutal jargons, scarcely sufficient even for their own needs" - more likely that even Orc-leaders didn't use BS for the simple reason that they couldn't: they didn't know it well enough to be able to use it.